# How to customize bcs columns as drop down from another table values in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, bcs

I am working on sharepoint online. I created Bcs of Employeesalary table. In that employeeID coming as textbox. But i need to **change the control as dropdownlist**

The datas for **dropdown from employee** table.

Is it possible using simple modification in infopath or have to do weebpart for that?

Is it possible means by webpart or anything else means, please give me some samples...

Comment: Anyone having any idea?